# get wfs layer polygon coordinates

Tags: openlayers, wfs

I have published a wfs layer in geoserver, and displayed that on the google map using openlayers. By using ol3 i am able to select the polygon, but iam not able to get the coordinates of the polygon. For selecting the polygon my code is

```
    var interaction;
    var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
        style: new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: '#FF2828'
            })
        })
    });


              interaction = new ol.interaction.Select({
        style: new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: '#f50057', width: 2})
            })
    });

    map.addInteraction(interaction);
```

How to get the cocordinates of the selected polygon in geojson format?

Comment: You can't select geometries over WMS (unless you make a modification to make a GetFeatureInfo query), are you using WFS?

Comment: sorry i am using wfs only, by mistake i have mentioned wms

Answer (score 3):

First, to get the selected features, use the *getFeatures* method from the select interaction object. Then, to get the geojson representation of this features, OL provides the *ol.format.GeoJSON* class, which you can use to convert the features (or only his geometries) to a json string.

Here is an example:

```
var toGeoJSON = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
var selectedFeatures = interaction.getFeatures();
selectedFeatures.forEach(function(feature){

    // To get the geojson representation of the geometry:
    var geomJSON = toGeoJSON.writeGeometry(feature.getGeometry());

    // To get the geojson representation of the feature:
    var featureJson = toGeoJSON.writeFeature(feature);
});
```

**EDIT**

Working example on fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/1Lpqxc53/

Comment: How to declare a feature in your code?Because when i run your code i am getting error as "feature.getGeometry() is not a function"

Comment: I've added a working example, now you can see how it works.